How to restrict AC power flow to one section of the load
Setup: I have a 2.2 kW inverter (input of which are solar panels) with which two floors of my home are connected at the output.
What I need: I want to distribute the power unequally between the two floors limiting a certain floor to consumer only a limited supply of the available power.
For example lets consider my inverter outputs 2 kW at a given time. I need to limit the power consumption of Floor 1 to 800 watts and whatever is remains over should be available for Floor 2.
Additional Information: The output voltage of inverter is 220 volts at ~50 Hz. I have a battery back up of 200 Ah (24 V) connected with my inverter.

In general, for a fixed supply voltage, the load determines the power drawn. To limit the power drawn you would need to control the voltage going to each floor (using two inverters) but your loads may not like operating on varying voltage and some loads such as switched mode power supplies used in computers have wide input ranges and will run at constant power over the full input voltage range.
The other option is to start switching loads off when a certain power demand has been detected. This has the problem that the loads may switch back on again when the new lower load is detected.
What you are asking for is not very easy.
